# Maven can't compile due to "package javafx.collections does not exist" error

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm currently doing a project with javafx using maven. When I run it direcly from the run button of IntelliJ it works fine, but when I try to compile it with Maven I get a lot of errors like this one:

`package javafx.collections does not exist`

I have the javafx dependency like this on my pom.xml, but it looks like Maven isn't getting it.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

A POM dependency doesn't pull in the actual code. JavaFX was included in older versions of Java, maybe your IntelliJ IDEA setup uses an old version that already contains JavaFX.

Comment: I ended up adding more dependencies on my pom like javafx-controls, javafx-media, javafx-graphics and javafx-fxml. That seemed to fix it.